# Is there any reason to escape a dot in a bash filename expansion?

Tags: bash, quoting

I am working with a bash script that someone else wrote and I see the following line:

```
cp -v  ${LOG_DIR}/${APPLICATION}\.*.log ${ARCHIVED_LOG_DIR}
```

The files with which it's working are all named like:

`EXAMPLE.command1.log`
`EXAMPLE.command2.log`

Is there any reason for the backslash escaping the dot since a dot isn't treated specially in filename expansions? What are the implications of doing this vs without the backslash as such?:

```
cp -v  ${LOG_DIR}/${APPLICATION}.*.log ${ARCHIVED_LOG_DIR}
```

Comment: Since `.` is not a [character that needs quoting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02), it looks like the backslash is entirely extraneous.  It may be a typo, or the person who wrote that line just felt like adding a backslash?

Comment: I agree that it was likely a typo but it made me curious whether there were any effective differences in the two commands or if the backslash is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.  The dot `.` is not a [special shell character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02) that needs quoting, and the backslash will simply be removed during [quote removal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_07).  This is true in most shells, not just `bash`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the supporting documentation for which I was looking.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question that has already been addressed by @jw013, but please note that while the `\` and `{}` are superfluous here, there are a few things missing. Like the variables should be quoted, and `--` to mark the end of options is missing.

```
cp -v -- "$LOG_DIR/$APPLICATION".*.log "$ARCHIVED_LOG_DIR"
```

Comment: I was going to mention this in a comment but didn't as it was not relevant to the question.  However all these adjustments are indeed necessary for maximum robustness.

Comment: @jw013, agreed, but I think it's worth mentioning. The `\ ` is misleading but harmless, the `{}` is cosmetic and a matter of taste, but the missing quotes or -- are *wrong*.